# Date (YYYY-MM-DD) not working as ID in HTML/Angular 2

Tags: html, json, date, angular, typescript

I have created a calendar with html in Angular 2, and now I want to put events in them, which color the day, puts a dot inside the cell or something. I have a json file with the data, where each "event" includes a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd, and some other attributes with information.
To get an easy connection between the calendar and data, I was hoping to give each cell an ID of the mentioned date format, but the requirement for IDs is to have at least 1 character, so I can't do it that way.

Are there any suggestions how I can sort this out?
It might be an advantage to know that this is a school calendar, so it only requires update once a year.

This is how my html looks like. I call a function to print each week of the calendar with month and year as input, and run it through an ngFor that returns 7 cells with ID (attr.id) from the json file (cell.id), and the day number in the cell (cell.text).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let cell of weekOne(8, 2016)" 
            [attr.id]="cell.id">{{cell.text}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let cell of otherWeeks(8, 2016)" 
            [attr.id]="cell.id">{{cell.text}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let cell of otherWeeks(8, 2016)" 
            [attr.id]="cell.id">{{cell.text}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let cell of otherWeeks(8, 2016)" 
            [attr.id]="cell.id">{{cell.text}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let cell of otherWeeks(8, 2016)" 
            [attr.id]="cell.id">{{cell.text}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The "events" in the json file looks like this:

```
{
    "pupilday": "No",
    "comment": "Planning day",
    "teacherday": "No",
    "school": "Auglend school",
    "﻿date": "2016-08-15"
},
etc......
```

If you need additional code to help, please give me a note.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an artificial character to make the id valid:

```
attr.id="_{{cell.id}}"
```

Comment: The plan was to somewhere have an if attr.id == (any of the date attributes in the json) to determine which cell to edit. To do this, I will need the same character in the json, or what? I can't add a character in the json date because of other functions in the program, so that's why this is difficult.

Comment: This is how browsers treat HTML, this is not related to Angular(2). You can use a different attribute where it's not required that the value starts with a character. Alternatively you can add the same character for `querySelector()` or whatever you use to query the element (as you mentioned). I don't understand why this would be difficult. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this id?

Comment: The cells are supposed to have an id or an other attribute which are the date in the yyyy-mm-dd format. The json file contains ONLY dates which are vacations and planning days from school. So those dates should look different in the calendar, in ex. change color or add a text. To know which table cells to edit, i was planning to use the mentioned "if attr.id == (any of the date attributes in the json)".

Comment: "or an other attribute" is the way to go then. Only the `id` attribute has the limitation that numbers are not valid for the first character.